# How to restart networking?

Tags: networking

After downloading an ubuntu update on 16 lts and restarting the computer, I cannot access internet anymore.  What should I try?

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart` from terminal.

Comment: I tried this command (service network-manager restart) and it did nothing good, even after restarting the computer several times.  So I had to go back to Windows, and after a while I tried Ubuntu again.... surprise!! my connections show again and connect automatically on startup.  I wonder why it takes a few attemps to get that command working...

Comment: post your `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn`